# Get a 3-Legged Token with Autodesk APS Authorization in a C# client - sample wanted

Tags: c#, oauth, autodesk-forge

I am currently trying to complete this step by step tutorial which is based on [Getting a 3-Legged Token with Authorization Code Grant](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/)

Is there a working example of a C# client that uses `System.Windows.Forms.Form` and includes the `WebBrowser` control.
Alternatively, it would be possible to use WPF/XAML to implement the login dialog.

Comment: We don't have an specific sample using window forms but we do have the entire process of using this type of authentication on a C# sample which should be pretty straight forward to sort out what you are trying to do - https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/auth